# How to GREP a substring in a line which a is variable assignment?

Tags: bash, shell

I have an output which is of the format

> OK: CpuUser=0.11; CpuNice=0.00; CpuSystem=0.12; CpuIowait=0.02; CpuSteal=0.00;

I want to get just the CpuIowait=0.12 as output. I want to grep just a specific substring.
How do I do that?

Comment: Why close this question? Bash/Shell specific questions are off limits?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `-o` ("only") flag. This command:

```
grep -o 'CpuIowait=[^;]*'
```

will print out the specific substrings that match `CpuIowait=[^;]*`, instead of printing out the whole lines that contain them.

Comment: For others finding this comment, if you want to use regex features like LookAhead/LookBehind use `-Po`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `grep`, try something like this:

```
echo "OK: CpuUser=0.11; CpuNice=0.00; CpuSystem=0.12; CpuIowait=0.02; CpuSteal=0.00;" | grep -oE "CpuIowait=[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*"
```

Comment: ruakh's answer is better though

Comment: While it probably won't happen, that regex will match "CpuIowait=."

Answer (score 2):

If you're not dead set on using `grep`, you can pipe the input to `sed`:

```
sed -ne "s/^.*\(CpuSystem=[0-9.]*\);.*$/\1/p;"
```

From `man sed`:

> `-n, --quiet, --silent`: suppress automatic printing of pattern space
>
> `-e script, --expression=script`: add the script to the commands to be executed

Answer (score 2):

To get the entire string:

```
var=$(grep -Eo 'CpuIowait=[0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{2}' < <(command))
```

To get just the value, if you have GNU grep with -P, you can use the following:

```
var=$(grep -Po '(?<=CpuIowait=).*(?=;)' < <(command))
```

Using awk:

```
var=$(awk -F'; |: ' '{ for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,arr,/=/); if (arr[1] ==  "CpuIowait") { print arr[2] } } }' < <(command))
```

Using pure bash:

```
output=$(command)
[[ $output =~ (CpuIowait=[0-9][.][0-9]{2}) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```